# SAS proc compare -- how to apply format to output values

Tags: sas

I have 2 datasets with datetime20. format assigned to AEEDTM variables
Yet I get only datepart displayed in the proc compare output:

---

```
IRR symptom end datetime
     Base    Compare
   IREDTM     IREDTM      Diff.
_________  _________  _________

14NOV2016  14NOV2016    59.0000
```

How can I force SAS to print formatted values in proc compare?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this _automatically_?  It's very easy to do manually (in the PROC PRINT call), but in the PROC COMPARE automatic output, I think it's a different story...

Comment: I mistyped my question, yes I want to do that within proc compare.

Comment: PROC COMPARE sucks in terms of option. I would ask Tech Support to make sure, but I don't think there's a way using PROC COMPARE. You can save the output table and customize from there, but that's not ideal. It might be possible to modify the template but IMO that's too difficult and it should be considered a date time from the start.